# How to reading data from MCCGQ02HL sensor by Python?

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, sensors

I am reading the open status of sensor mccgq02hl. I have encrypted and read data on a similar Xiaomi lywsd03mmc.. however when I change the UUID of mccgq02hl. it doesn't notify nor read data.

For more details, I want to write a code to read the status of mccgq02hl sensor by Python on Window OS. I have not tried pygatt because of not fully supported for window (support for Linux).

Currently, I'm using Bleak python library for the lywsd03mmc sensor which can be read and notify temperate and humid data. But not working for mccgq02hl sensor (open/close status).

This is my [code](https://github.com/hxtruong6/connect-ble-sensor/blob/9885e7b703636e0ce983bfd18476ce8329de71a9/main.py):

```py
import logging
import asyncio

from bleak import BleakClient
from bleak import _logger as logger

CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = "f000aa65-0451-4000-b000-000000000000"  # <--- Change to the characteristic you want to enable notifications from.
ADDRESS = "24:71:89:cc:09:05"  # <--- Change to your device's address here if you are using Windows or Linux

SLEEP_TIME = 2
TIME_OUT = 20


def notification_handler(sender, data):
    """Simple notification handler which prints the data received."""
    print("---> Notification handler:\t {0}: {1}".format(sender, data))


def disconnect_callback(client: BleakClient):
    print("xxxxx Client with address {} got disconnected!".format(client.address))


async def connect_to_device(address: str, debug=True):
    if debug:
        import sys
        l = logging.getLogger("asyncio")
        l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        h = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        h.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        l.addHandler(h)
        logger.addHandler(h)

    while True:
        print("Waiting connect to sensor....")
        try:
            async with BleakClient(address, timeout=TIME_OUT, disconnected_callback=disconnect_callback) as client:
                # await client.connect();
                is_connected = await client.is_connected()
                if is_connected:
                    print("Connected to Device")

                    await client.start_notify(
                        CHARACTERISTIC_UUID, notification_handler,
                    )
                    while True:
                        if not is_connected:
                            print("Device disconnected!!!")
                            break
                        await asyncio.sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
                        print("=========")

                    # await client.stop_notify(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID)
                else:
                    print(f"Failed to connect to Device")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Exception when connect: {e}")

        print(f"\n---Reconnect! Sleep {SLEEP_TIME} seconds!")
        await asyncio.sleep(SLEEP_TIME)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.set_debug(True)
    task = asyncio.ensure_future(connect_to_device(ADDRESS, debug=True))
    loop.run_until_complete(task)
```

So my questions are how to read data from mccgq02hl sensor in Python on Window?

Comment: Using a generic Bluetooth Low Energy scanning and exploration tool like [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile) first is often best. Once you know what the process is for getting the characteristics value, then doing it in Python is easier. Looking at the following page suggests their maybe a requirement for a bindkey for that sensor. https://esphome.io/components/sensor/xiaomi_ble.html#id2

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. I have used nRF app to get UUID (such as 3,4 values) but none of them work with mccgq02hl sensor. Anyways, many thanks.

Comment: Do you get any log output from your code? What exactly is not working?

Comment: I can read the name of device. But about status value (open/close door), the code can not get any notify data.